# Facebook AppRequest for single friend

Tags: android, facebook

I am able to create app request in facebook but my requirement is to send app request for only 1 friend among all the friend list. Please need your help to send App request for only one user without option for selecting multiple friendlist Thanks for your concern.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", getString(R.string.request_message));
Utility.mFacebook.dialog(Hackbook.this, "apprequests", params, new AppRequestsListener());
```

Comment: can notification can be send.. with app request..

Answer (score 2):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle(); params.putString("to", String.valueOf(fbUid)); 
params.putString("message", getString(R.string.request_message));    
Utility.mFacebook.dialog(BoardActivity.this, "apprequests", params, new PostDialogListener());
```